# Quickblox android QBCustomObjects.deleteObjects is not working

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I'm using `Quickblox` sdk 3.3.0 
There is something wrong with sdk or i'm using it in wrong way?

```
  int count = QBCustomObjects.countObjects("tbl_taxi_gps", req).perform();
                if (count > 30) {
                    req = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
                    req.eq("uid", qbUser.getId());
                    ArrayList<QBCustomObject> list = QBCustomObjects.getObjects("tbl_taxi_gps", req, new Bundle()).perform();
                    final StringifyArrayList<String> rem = new StringifyArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i == 31; i++)
                        //QBCustomObjects.deleteObject("tbl_taxi_gps", list.get(i).getCustomObjectId());
                        rem.add(list.get(i).getCustomObjectId());
                    QBCustomObjects.deleteObjects("tbl_taxi_gps", rem).perform();


                    Log.w("LocationService", "deleted");
                }
```

when i use `QBCustomObjects.deleteObject("tbl_taxi_gps", list.get(i).getCustomObjectId());`
it's work fine but if i try to delete multiple objects this will happen:

```
       =========================================================
                                                         === REQUEST ==== 15e62680-8979-4d7c-8d36-9e3eef421fcf ===
                                                         REQUEST
                                                             DELETE https://api.quickblox.com/data/tbl_taxi_gps/.json
                                                         HEADERS
                                                             QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                                             QB-SDK=Android 3.3.0
                                                             QB-Token=704c5e5a589xxf8a24bxx78xx850ddexx900cd6b
                                                         PARAMETERS

                                                         INLINE
                                                             DELETE https://api.quickblox.com/data/tbl_taxi_gps/.json
   02-26 08:55:42.001 7063-7319/com.sss.taxi:main D/QBASDK: *********************************************************
                                                         *** RESPONSE *** 15e62680-8979-4d7c-8d36-9e3eef421fcf ***
                                                         STATUS : 404 
                                                         HEADERS
                                                             X-Runtime=0.007143
                                                             Cache-Control=no-cache
                                                             X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
                                                             QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                                             X-Android-Selected-Protocol=http/1.1
                                                             X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
                                                             Status=404 Not Found
                                                             X-Request-Id=8bdc1f2e9ead87d9a91dfef128735b2b
                                                             X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 404
                                                             Connection=Close
                                                             X-Android-Sent-Millis=1488128141405
                                                             Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
                                                             Date=Sun, 26 Feb 2017 16:55:44 GMT
                                                             Server=openresty/1.9.15.1
                                                             Content-Length=44
                                                             X-Android-Received-Millis=1488128141999
                                                             Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
                                                         BODY
                                                             '{"code":null,"message":"Resource not found"}'
  02-26 08:55:42.002 7063-7319/com.sss.taxi:main W/System.err: com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: Entity you are looking for was not found.,Resource not found
  02-26 08:55:42.003 7063-7319/com.sss.taxi:main W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBJsonParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  02-26 08:55:42.003 7063-7319/com.sss.taxi:main W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.auth.session.Query.perform(Unknown Source)
  02-26 08:55:42.003 7063-7319/com.sss.taxi:main W/System.err:     at com.sss.taxi.GPS.LocationService.run(LocationService.java:93)
  02-26 08:55:42.003 7063-7319/com.sss.taxi:main W/LocationService: errr
```

the problem is in request address.

in other requests it point to correct address : `https://api.quickblox.com/data/tbl_taxi_gps.json`
but if i use `QBCustomObjects.deleteObjects(...)` it will point to : `https://api.quickblox.com/data/tbl_taxi_gps/.json`

is this a bug ?

is there any way to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of debugging and trying different ways i found out
this should be my output  `/classname/id1,id2,id3.json` and i've got `/classname/.json` 
so the problem was with getting ids from `list`